# Why does a while loop prevent a case structure from changing states, and how can I fix it?

Tags: while-loop, case, structure, labview

For a project, I need to write a program in LabVIEW that accepts three inputs from the user (amplitude, phase, and frequency) and stores those values in EEPROM when the user presses the 'save' button.

When the user presses the select save button, the program should collect the data stored in the EEPROM and generate a sine wave on a graph based on the data.

My current program is below.

[image: LabVIEW diagram]

If the save button is pressed before running the VI, the program works fine until it needs to generate the sine wave. Once it generates the sine wave, it no longer responds to any input.

Removing the inner while loop, which generates and plots the sine wave, solves the issue. As a result, I'm wondering why a while loop prevents the case structure from changing cases.

Comment: The outer while loop does not restart until the inner loop that generates the sine wave is done, which only happens once you press stop. I guess your program is unresponsive while cycling that inner loop but that should be easy to see using Labview's debugger and step-by-step execution. Anyway, you should probably restructure so that the outer loop generates only a single sample of the sine wave before re-checking its inputs. Or even better, use an event structure inside the loop and use the timeout event to update the sine wave, if active

Comment: Or separate the loops entirely and let them run in parallel

Comment: As @Homer512 already suggested a event structure is a better practice here. If the problem is that you cant stop you cannot stop once your sin generation is active, then most probably your stop button is not pressed. You have two while loops and two different buttons to stop each loop. Consider using local variables here or property nodes here for a more automized behavior. In addition have a look at the state-machine pattern. There is also a dynamic state-machine that is able to react to user changes even without event structures. But anyway: eventstructures are a much better practice :)